# If $R$ is a integral domain then $TM$ is torsion module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be an integral domain. An $R$-module $M$ is *torsion* if $TM = M$.

> Prove that $TM$ is torsion.

I'm confused with this exercise, i need to prove that $TTM = TM$ but we know that $TM$ is a submodule if $R$ is an integral domain then $TM ≤ M $. Please some help for this, ty.

Comment: No, you need to prove that $TTM = T M$

Comment: and can you give some hint for this

Comment: $TM$ means the set of elements $m\in M$ such that for some nonzero $r\in R$, we have $rm=0$. Okay, so what is $TTM$? It's the set of all $m\in TM$ such that for some nonzero $r\in R$, we have $rm=0$. They look similar enough, don't they?

Comment: By what you have written, you just need to prove that $TTM\subset TM$, but $m \in TTM$, then $xm = 0$ for some $x \in R$, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $T(TM) \subseteq TM$, observe that

\begin{align*}
m \in T(TM) & \iff m \in TM \text{ and there exists } r \in R : rm = 0 \\
& \implies m \in TM
\end{align*}

and to show that $TM \subseteq T(TM)$, observe that

\begin{align*}
m \in TM & \iff m \in M \text{ and there exists } s \in R : sm = 0 \\
& \implies m \in TM \text{ and there exists } s \in R : sm = 0 \\
& \iff m \in T(TM).
\end{align*}

Conclude that $T(TM) = TM$.